# When i am trying to upload it in market it shows.. "You need to reduce your APK file size to 50MB or use APK Expansion Files."

Tags: android

My project apk file size is 101mb,When i am trying to upload it in market it shows.. "You need to reduce your APK file size to 50MB or use APK Expansion Files."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Market Allow to upload 50MB of apk in play store.

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en&

Comment: Can anyone please explain me the procedure to resolve this issue..

Comment: load ur most of data into server.

Comment: I am not using any server..

Comment: then u should have to reduce image size or whatever u reduce in ur app.

Comment: I reduced all the images size..but still it shows 101mb...Please suggest

Comment: what u want from us sandy u have to use server for this problem bcz ur all data in server and allow to user for download data from sever through apk..

Comment: Can anyone please explain me the procedure of creating expansion files???????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9596955/apk-expansion-files

Comment: Thanks..But i need the procedure with best example...i didnt understand that procedure...we have to put any code in our java class files??Please help me...